# How to add a Image in a SurfaceView in a blinking image format in Android

Tags: android, image, surfaceview

I would like to add an Image to a SurfaceView and the image should blink at regular time intervals. I am able to add the image to the SurfaceView, but I am unable to make it blink. Please tell me a  method for making image disappear after being been added to the SurfaceView.

Comment: code pls. Ideally you should be painting something over ur surfaceview and display that before u make the image visible again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Thread` within your extended `SurfaceView` class to perform the animations you need. You should study the Lunar Lander example project, which demonstrates the concept very well.